# Eliminate unknown function $f$ by obtaining a PDE

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

*Question*
Let the funcion $z = z(x,y)$ be given by the equation $z = xy + f(x^2 -y)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary $C^1$ function. By forming the first partial derivatives of $z = z(x,y)$: $p = z_x$ and $q = z_y$, eliminate the unknown function $f$ by obtaining a PDE.

*Attempt*

$$ z_x = \frac{\delta z}{\delta x} = y + 2xf'(x^2 - y) = p $$
$$ z_y = \frac{\delta z}{\delta y} = x - f'(x^2 - y) = q $$

Moving things around

$$ \frac{y - p}{2x} = f'(x^2 - y) = x + q$$

giving us

$$ y - z_x = 2x^2 + 2x \cdot z_y$$

That's my answer. Is that right?

Also, where can I read more on this method and can you give me a little bit of background on the role of this in the grander scheme of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning with division for zero! 
However, 
$$
z_x+2xz_y=(y+2xf'(x^2-y))+2x(x-f'(x^2-y))=y+2x^2,
$$
i.e.,
$$
z_x+2xz_y-y-2x^2=0.
$$

Comment: Oh, thanks! I always forget about the zero. So is this it? I'm always suspicious of questions that require what appears to be so little work, especially because it's a fourth-year course. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Siyanda, Yes! Note that had a signal error!